# What to replace this java code with?

Tags: java, applet, audio

The following code is used for playing a sound file in my java applet:

```
public synchronized void play() {
   try {
          //Here filename is a URL retreived through
          //getClassLoader().getResource()
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename.getFile());
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It works when i run the applet locally using Eclipse, but if I try packaging it in a .jar and running it as an applet in the web browser, it doesn't work. Commenting out this code makes the applet work.

What shall I substitute the above code with so it'll work in the applet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using getResourceAsStream() on the ClassLoader instead of new FileInputStream().  This will return an InputStream that you can pass to the AudioStream.  So something like:

```
InputStream in = getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getClassLoader().getResource());
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in)
```

Answer (score 4):

Either use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [URL.openStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()). Remember to close your streams to avoid resource leaks.

Alternatively, check to see if the [AudioClip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html) class suits your needs:

```
  private AudioClip sound = null;

  private AudioClip getSound() {
    if (sound == null) {
      ClassLoader classLoader = TestApplet.class
          .getClassLoader();
      URL url = classLoader.getResource("assets/sound.wav");
      sound = JApplet.newAudioClip(url);
    }
    return sound;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` instead of `new FileInputStream(...)`. There's no local file involved here (potentially, e.g. when using a jar file). Basically you want to get a stream to the sound data, and when you're fetching a resource from the classpath, `getResourceAsStream()` is the simplest way of doing that.

(You can use `getResource()` followed by `openStream()` if you want, but there's not much point.)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) method in the `java.lang.ClassLoader` class.

This will still work even if you don't have a JAR as long as the relevant files are in your `CLASSPATH`.